# Ethereum balance not confirmed by online blockchain explorers

Tags: balances

When doing `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` on my geth machine I get some non-empty balance. When checking the same account in one of many online blockchain explorers, this account is either non-existent or zero. Who's right and what did go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your local node fully synchronised? If so the balance returned from `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` is likely correct.

Blockchain explorers work by syncing the blockchain, and reading the data.

As they do this for every block/transaction, it may simply be the case that there is a delay - they have yet to process the transaction, and thus can not display it on their website.

Comment: Indeed, although it wasn't syncing when I checked it, now it resumed and the balance is 0...